# UFW rules allow traffic, but iptable blocks it

Tags: iptables, firewall, ufw

I've just learned that my default Ubuntu 18.04 VM comes with UFW. According to [the Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall), UFW:

> is a frontend for iptables and is particularly well-suited for host-based firewalls.

Upon installation, ufw is disabled, so I was pretty surprised that iptables was *not* disabled. In fact, it was blocking a lot of traffic.

Now I enabled UFW and told it what kind of traffic I expect to flow in:

```sh
ufw enable
ufw logging on
ufw allow "OpenSSH"
ufw allow "Nginx Full"
ufw reload
ufw status verbose
```

Output from the last command:

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full)    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp (OpenSSH)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full (v6)) ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (OpenSSH (v6))      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

So far, so good.

But to my surprise, HTTP traffic on port 80 is *still* being blocked by iptables. Flushing all rules and chains (`iptables -F`) lets the incoming HTTP traffic flow to nginx.

My question is two-fold:

1. What is the relationship between UFW and iptables, if UFW can be *disabled* when iptables is *running*, and UFW can say HTTP traffic is allowed while iptables blocks it?
2. How can I get iptables to indeed follow the UFW configuration, so that I have one tool to configure and check?

Comment: Leave UFW out of it, for now. After a re-boot do `sudo iptables -v -x -n -L` and edit your question to include the output. There are default iptables rules for VM hosts. (Note: I do not use UFW, but do use iptables.)

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @MarcoSchoolenberg, I ended up with `firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp --add-port=443/tcp --add-port=22/tcp` followed by `firewall-cmd --reload`. I don't know why, but after that, it worked...

Comment: Thanks. @mthmulders  It's very confusing. It seems at some point in time Ubuntu took "UFW" and made it into more then just a front end. I noticed that some of the older guides don't work after upgrading to 18.04 to higher.